# How to replace words on blogger theme with image?

Tags: image, templates, header, blogger

I have created a 960x100 image to take the place of the header words on this blogger theme. Does anyone know how this can be accomplished? Need an expert! :-)

http://selfemployedmavens.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

For a new style blogger layout with a header element, use the Image instead of title and description option.

Or if you want to get your hands dirty, CSS image replacement on the `h1#title` element.  Any of the techniques here

http://css-tricks.com/nine-techniques-for-css-image-replacement/

that don't require extra markup should work.